# Sigma electron movement in resonance forms

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance

I have come across an example in my textbook, which shows resonance structures for the bromonium ion. However, I am confused as to why the sigma bond electrons "move" to get the tertiary carbocation and the secondary carbocation. Are sigma bond electrons not strictly localized and pi electrons delocalized?

[image]
My question is: **When are we allowed to move the sigma electrons when writing resonance forms?**

Comment: In the text, which talks about the diagram says this: "In resonance terms, we say that the weighting factor (coefficient) for the more-stable form is greater than that for the less-stable form (c1 > c2, Fig. 11.13)." Are you sure these are not resonance forms?

Comment: Yes, I am sure these are rearrangement structures, see Wagner-Meerwein rearrangement in my answer. And yes the factor which decide the major product is the stability of intermediate (here carbocation).

Comment: @Mithoron there are multiple descriptions possible, but they would involve sigma type orbitals on MO and VB theory. That doesn't make your point and more value. The bromonium is a very good example for nonclassical cations. // Very approximate rule of thumb: as long as you don't move the nuclei, you can use (for better or worse) the concept of resonance. (Here it's actually for better.)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン I think it can be also viewed as an analogue of alkene - metal complex.

Comment: @Mithoron yes indeed. The pi orbital would still do a sigma type donation. There was a typo in my last comment (I'm on my phone), it should have been: that doesn't make your point any less valid.